# How to clean window history in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

Right now I'm having this issue in Eclipse where I have an XML file open that's really big in which it almost crashes Eclipse. However this file being opened is saved in my window history, therefore I restart eclipse, it tries to open this massive file again. How do I clear the opened window history in eclipse?

I would prefer not having to clear my workspace entirely as I have mylyn data I want to keep. I've tried using Eclipse clean but this doesn't seem to do anything related to opened windows.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your workbench information are saved in this file in your workspace:

```
.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.ui.workbench/workbench.xml
```

or depending on your eclipse version:

```
.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.e4.workbench/workbench.xmi
```

You can delete it and eclipse will recreate the file, you can also try to edit it, but it's a big file and may be hard... Deleting this file all workbench related settings are lost but your projects stays intact.

Comment: You saved my day. I always deleted whole WS when Eclipse could not start. This is nicer since projects or other configurations are not lost.

Answer (score 4):

Go to Preferences and search for 'workspace'. You will see the list of workspaces that you can delete.

Comment: This did not answer the question asked, but it did answer the question I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Some alternatives:
Move or rename the offensive file so that eclipse is unable to open it.
File->Switch Workspace->Other to load a new workspace copying your workbench layout.

Just some thoughts, my experience is closing a file and then the program means that the program will not attempt to open the file once launched again.